# Page content not showing in one theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site that has a custom theme. WordPress is not my framework of choice, so I'm a bit of a novice. There are 2 scenarios happening.

1. Theme shows content fine on Hosting A
2. Theme does not show content on Hosting B
3. TwentyTwelve and TwentyEleven show content on Hosting B

So, there seems to be something wrong with the custom theme on Hosting B, however, nothing sticks out. I've deleted and reimported the theme, still with no success. I've copied over the page.php file (again for sanity), still with no success. I've deactivated and reactivated all plugins one by one just to see if it was one of those, again, with no success.

Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: not showing how? your pages aren't being built with those themes? or css/images are missing?

Comment: @MarcB literally the content. Page.php does not seem to render, everything else does, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having issues like this with a theme on one host but not another, it's possible the theme is using a deprecated PHP function, has warnings, etc.

If Host B has less forgiving server rules, it sounds like they might be halting the request (which results in a white page for your users).

Your best bet would be to either find the error logs for Host B, or perhaps loosen the restrictions and allow errors and warning messages.  Of course, you'll want this to be a setting in your development environment (not on a production site).

I use the [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin to also help surface any issues while in development.